# I want to get a list of Active Directory users with the AccountExpires but the property returns empty on all users

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Properties DisplayName, title, Department, Office, OfficePhone, EmailAddress, wWWHomePage, AccountExpires -SearchBase '****' |
Sort-Object -Property DisplayName | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Title, Department, Office, OfficePhone, EmailAddress, wWWHomePage, AccountExpires | Export-Csv -LiteralPath C:\PowerShell\temp1.csv
```

Is the `AccountExpires` the correct property to look at to obtain this date?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rTiv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `Get-AdUser`, use the `AccountExpirationDate` property, since it formats the date for you. When using `AccountExpiry`, an example date looks like `133035804000000000`. Using `AccountExpirationDate` instead gives you `2022-07-30 01:00:00`.

If there's no expiry date set on the account, `AccountExpirationDate` returns NULL.

If you use `AccountExpires` and there's no expiry date, it'll return either `0` or `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (9223372036854775807)`. I've noticed that PS will often not process that long value properly when going through a pipeline or exporting.

It's often best to simply run your basic command first to see what results you get before running it through the pipeline. Or try it with one user where you know an expiry date has been set.

```
> Get-ADUser myUser -Properties AccountExpirationDate, DisplayName, title, Department, Office, OfficePhone, EmailAddress, wWWHomePage

AccountExpirationDate : 2022-07-30 01:00:00
Department            : CM
DisplayName           : MY User
DistinguishedName     : MYUSER,OU=Users,OU=MyOU,DC=example,DC=com
EmailAddress          : My.User@example.com
Enabled               : True
GivenName             : My
Name                  : My User
ObjectClass           : user
ObjectGUID            : 1234aaaa-30b9-45ad-98af-12345abcdef
Office                : CM Address
OfficePhone           : (055) 555 9535
SamAccountName        : My User
SID                   : S-1-5-21-123456789-0123454678-1238779560-660873
Surname               : User
Title                 : Technical Specialist
UserPrincipalName     : MY.User@example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `AccountExpirationDate` property:

```sh
$properties = 'DisplayName', 'title', 'Department', 'Office', 'OfficePhone', 'EmailAddress', 'wWWHomePage', 'AccountExpirationDate'
Get-ADUser -filter {AccountExpirationDate -like '*'} -Properties $properties | 
  Sort-Object DisplayName |
  Select-Object $properties |
  Export-CSV C:\PowerShell\temp1.csv
```

---

[AccountExpires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-accountexpires) is not date-formatted, but can be used if you need it. It should not be blank:

> A value of 0 or 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (9223372036854775807) indicates that the account never expires.

Comment: Whoops, noticed this after posting the same suggestion re `AccountExpirationDate`

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Properties DisplayName, title, Department, Office, OfficePhone, EmailAddress, wWWHomePage, AccountExpires -SearchBase '<your searchbase>' |sort displayname | Export-Csv -LiteralPath C:\PowerShell\temp1.csv
```

You don't need to select the objects again as you allready did so with the -properties parameter.

Working like a charm on my end.

Comment: Doing a `Select` is pretty standard if you don't want to export all the other default properties that `Get-ADUser` will return (e.g. `objectClass`, `GUID` ,`SID`).